# How to fade out SnackBar bottom to top

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I have the following `Activity` where users can post comments. If there is no internet connection I am showing message to user in a `SnackBar` on top of the screen because at the bottom I have `EditText`. Now the problem is that `SnackBar` is fading out `top-to-bottom` like in the 2nd image. I was wondering if it's possible to change this behavior so that it would fade out `bottom-to-top`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you make a gif on how that snackbar is fading ? im not getting you quite right

Comment: well it just like the first image and then it slides down like in the second image and then disappears

Comment: oh, now i get it !

Comment: https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar check this out dude

Comment: yeah that exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated above you can use this library:

https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar

To implement it just do this steps

In your gradle module app (do not use compile as it will discontinued soon)

```
implementation'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:1.1.1'
```

As this is in Maven, you can check the latest version of the library just by clicking here

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.androidadvance/topsnackbar

[image]

What OP is needing is the first example, to do it just simply add this to your onCreate (or whenever you want it)

```
TSnackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Hello from TSnackBar.",TSnackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```